# How to support multiple versions of a Python dependency?

Tags: python

I am writing a python utility which has to support multiple LTS versions of a python library. Let's say the LTS versions are '1.0' and '2.0'.

In 2.0 of the library has methods which have a different signature compared to 1.0, example:

```
# Version 1.0
def display_name(self, name):
    ...

# Version 2.0
def display_name(self, name, param_2):
    ...
```

Now based on which version the user wants to use, my utility tool needs to call the method `display_name` with different set of parameters.

Now my question is how to support multiple versions of a Python dependency? There are not many changes, total such major differences are like 10 odd.

### So far what I have tried / come up with, are following ideas (other ideas are more than welcome):

1. Create 2 different versions of my library which support the 2 different versions. Keep the version name similar to main library so people can relate to that, and a verification when library is loaded to make sure supported main tool is installed.
2. Have 1 version of my library and add some sort of if condition check before each such method call which expects different parameter, and based on the version call the different methods. How lots of libraries support python 2.* and 3.*
3. Extending on option 2, is there some type of decorator pattern that can be written which delegates which version of a method will be loaded/called?

Example:

```
# Is something like this possible?
@lib_ves_1
def my_lib_method(self, args):
    ...
    main_lib.display_name(name)

@lib_ves_2
def my_lib_method(self, args):
    ...
    main_lib.display_name(name, param_2)
```

PS: Any other approach/idea is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Just because a question (in your opinion) is opinion based, does not mean it's a bad question. This question follows the guidelines set for asking a difficult question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278843/how-to-ask-the-elusive-good-question-without-becoming-primarily-opinion-based.

Comment: I am asking how can 'x' be done, and I have shared what all I have tried so far. 'Options' != 'Opinion'.

Comment: Obviously if it is closed and not reopened, this is not just my opinion... And this is not about labeling a question bad or good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your option (2) - checking for the library version before each call, you can either define the right version of your functions in import time:

```
import thelib

if thelib.__version__ >= 2.0:
    def my_function():
        return thelib.action1(43, 21)
else:
    def my_function():
        return thelib.action1(43)
```

Maybe even better is to define a thin wrapper over the library, that unifies the calls, so that you have all the "differences" in one place, and your actual code does not have to branch for that purpose. This is pretty much what the tool six - a compatibility layer between python2 and 3 - does.

```
import thelib

if thelib.__version__ >= 2.0:
    def action1_wrapper():
        return thelib.action1(43, 21)
else:
    def action1_wrapper():
        return thelib.action1(43)

def my_library_function():
    # ...
    action1_wrapper()
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, defining it at import time makes sense. that will help with reducing the if checks. I have upvoted the answers. Sorry SO if of the 'opinion' that my question is 'opinion' based, so they are downvoting everything. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not accepting the answer because I am hoping for some other solution which can do this with some decorators maybe, that would make it really simple. But thanks for the help :)